# Android show input always in Orientation.portrait

Tags: android

I would like to show the input ALWAYS `((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))`

when I am in:

```
Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE mode
```

AFTER enter is clicked or Send is clicked on the input.

I tried this:

```
if (event != null && 
    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && 
    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (Screen.getScreenOrientation(mycontext) == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
        Utils.hideInput(mycontext, EditTextSend);
    else
        Utils.showInput(mycontext, EditTextSend);
```

But that is not working for me.
Is it possible to not hide the input only when the user click *back*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was as simple as:

```
return true;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can control keyboard visibility per `Activity` in your `manifest`, check out:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

To display the keyboard *always* use:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" ... />
```